# Using signature of implemented method on Derived class for inherited method from Base class in a "template method pattern" inheritance in Python

Tags: python, python-typing

Consider we have [Template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) inheritance scenario. I am using an example with requests library.

```py
import abc
import json
import requests
from typing import Dict, Any

class Base(abc.ABC)
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def call(self, *args, **kwargs) -> requests.Response:
        raise NotImplementedError

    def safe_call(self, *args, **kwargs) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        try:
            response = self.call(*args, **kwargs)
            response.raise_for_status()
            return response.json()
        except json.JSONDecodeError as je: ...
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as ce: ...
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout as te: ...
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as he: ...
        except Exception as e: ...
        return {"success": False}


class Derived(Base):
    def call(self, url: str, json: Dict[str, Any], timeout: int, retries: int) -> requests.Response:
        # actual logic for making the http call
        response = requests.post(url, json=json, timeout=timeout, ...)
        return response
```

which will be used like

```py
executor = Derived()
response = executor.safe_call(url='https://example.com', json={"key": "value"}, ...)
```

Is there a way to attach the signature of `Derived.call` to `Derived.safe_call` so modern IDE auto-complete and type checkers work?
Because this awfully looks like a decorator pattern, I tried using `functools.update_wrapper` in `__init__` but that fails with

```
AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

I do have a few options in mind, but I am unable to find any recommendations on this problem

1. I can go the metaclass route to change up signature and docstring attributes before the class is completely constructed. However, this might not work well with IDEs.
2. I can define a stub file `.pyi` and maintain it along with the main code.

```py
class Derived(Base):
    def safe_call(self, url: str, json: Dict[str, Any], timeout: int, retries: int) -> Dict[str, Any]: ...
```

3. Change the design to something else completely
4. (Edit: Added post first answer) (Ab)use `@typing.overload`

```py
class Derived(Base):
    @typing.overload
    def safe_call(self, url: str, json: Dict[str, Any], timeout: int, retries: int) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        ...

    def call(self, url: str, json: Dict[str, Any], timeout: int, retries: int) -> requests.Response:
        # actual logic for making the http call
        response = requests.post(url, json=json, timeout=timeout, ...)
        return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see what you're trying to do, but I think it is probably a mistake to go down that route, as it would  break the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle?wprov=sfti1).

Currently, your abstract class `Base` defines an interface in which the method `Base.call` can, in concrete implementations of the interface, be called with *any positional or keyword arguments* without raising an error at runtime. From a theoretical point of view, your concrete implementation of `call` in your `Derived` class does not satisfy this interface. If it is called with >4 arguments, called with <4 arguments, or called with keyword-arguments that are not `url`, `json`, `timeout` or `retries`, it will raise an error at runtime.

Python will nonetheless let you *instantiate* instances of `Derived` at runtime, as it only checks for the presence of a method by the same name as the abstract method defined in `Base`. It does not check for signature compatibility of abstract methods upon instantiation of a concrete implementation, and attempting to do so would be extremely difficult. However, some type checkers may complain that the signature in your derived class is less permissive than in your base class. Moreover, the theoretical principle is important in its own right.

I think the way to go would probably be something like this. Note two things here:

1. The `safe_call` and `call` methods in the base class have both become private methods, as they are implementation details that are not designed to be used directly.
2. I have altered the signature of `call` and `safe_call` in the base class so that they only accept keyword arguments.

```
import abc
import json
import requests
from typing import Dict, Any

class Base(abc.ABC)
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _call(self, **kwargs: Any) -> requests.Response:
        raise NotImplementedError

    def _safe_call(self, **kwargs: Any) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        try:
            response = self.call(**kwargs)
            response.raise_for_status()
            return response.json()
        except json.JSONDecodeError as je: ...
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as ce: ...
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout as te: ...
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as he: ...
        except Exception as e: ...
        return {"success": False}


class Derived(Base):
    def _call(self, **kwargs: Any) -> requests.Response:
        url: str = kwargs['url']
        json: Dict[str, Any] = kwargs['json']
        timeout: int = kwargs['timeout']
        retries: int = kwargs['retries']
        
        # actual logic for making the http call
        response = requests.post(url, json=json, timeout=timeout, ...)
        return response

    def safe_call_specific_to_derived(self, url: str, json: Dict[str, Any], timeout: int, retries: int) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        return self._safe_call(url=url, json=json, timeout=timeout, retries=retries)
```

If you want to have default values for parameters in your concrete implementations of `_call`, note that you can use `kwargs.get(<arg_name>, <default_val>)` instead of `kwargs[<arg_name>]`

Comment: This relaying approach did cross my mind, specifically, implement `Derived.safe_call` with the specific signature that just relays the call as `super().safe_call(...)`. I was a bit hesitant with this as it increases the work for the implementor. Alas, it seems like the necessary evil that is least magical.

On another note, is LSP violated in this particular case if Base is abstract and non-instantiable for all practical purposes?

Comment: @chiragjn — yes, the LSP applies just as much to abstract interfaces as it does to inheriting from concrete classes. In fact, arguably more so, since an abstract class — by nature of its "uninstantiability" — serves no purpose other than to exist as an interface, an "abstract template" for subclasses. And if that  template is violated in every subclass of the abstract class, it's not really an accurate or useful template, is it?

Comment: Also, note that if you implement `safe_call` with a less permissive signature in a subclass than in the base class, that will *also* violate the LSP, hence why I recommended that you give the method with the accurate signature a unique name in each subclass (`safe_call_specific_to_foo` in class `Foo`, `safe_call_specific_to_bar` in class `Bar`, etc. Doesn't need to be that verbose in real life, obviously).

Comment: @chiragjn -- PEP 612 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/) might actually be of great use here, but unfortunately MyPy doesn't fully support it yet (https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8645), so I can't check out whether the usage I'm imagining would actually work here.